# Jmeter regex ignore first character

Tags: jmeter

Hey guys I'm new to jmeter and I'm trying to extract an expression using regular expression extractor.
It works fine but my expression has an " at the beginning and I want to ignore it
Any idea how to do it?
I currently use : guid:(.{1,36})

Comment: Can you provide an example and the expected match ?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the quotation mark outside of the grouping i.e.

```
guid:"(.{1,36})
```

alternatively you can use a regular expression which will match a GUID-like structure:

```
([a-f0-9]{8}(-[a-f0-9]{4}){4}[a-f0-9]{8})
```

More information:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Going forward please include at least partial response into your question because it's quite hard to come up with a comprehensive answer without seeing the source text.